# How to limit QHeaderView size (when resizing sections)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

`QHeaderView` sections can go out of view (to the right) when resizing. That is I can resize a section to be too big and other sections will disappear to the right.

Is it possible to limit this? Such as set max width of header.

I tried `setMaximumWidth` on table and header (actually in the real app I have just header without standard table) but it didn't help.

[image]

UPD:

Actually I want other columns to shrink instead of going out of visible area, something like in MS Word:

[image]

So if there is no built-in option for behavior like this, then I guess I need to find a suitable signal to adjust sizes after resizing, such as decreasing/increasing size of the next or previous column...

Comment: Hmm, have you tried setting `minimumSectionSize : int`?

Comment: Yes, why would it help? They don't shrink, they just go out of the visible area (see the scrollbar). Even when max widget/header size is limited.

Comment: There are signals i. e. QHeaderView::geometriesChanged(). You need one which tells you the header (column) is being resized. Then you allow the column being moved as along as all columns are within table->viewport()->width(). This is just an idea and not tested.

Comment: How about header()->setStretchLastSection(true)?

Or ingeneral, using QHeaderView::Stretch as ResizeMode for some columns.

Comment: I have one strech column, but what does it change? I just want to have some "fixed" area for table and when user resizes one column others columns should shrink instead of going out of visible area and adding scrollbar. Updated my question.

Comment: I cannot find any built-in for what you want. I guess you'd have to manage this yourself by resizing the next columns when the user is resizing a column, though I don't see any direct access to that event *column-resize*.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 5.12 set

```
QHeaderView()->setCascadingSectionResizes(true);
```

and

```
QHeaderView()->setSectionResizeMode(c, QHeaderView::Stretch);
c = lastColumn;
```

Comment: 5.12? According to the docs these functions exist since 4.2-5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as some comments have said, you can use signals from the `QHeaderView` to listen for changes and subsequently change them using `resizeSection()`. Below I have written a `AutoResizer` which performs your wanted resizing.

**AutoResizer.hpp**

```
#ifndef AUTORESIZER_HPP
#define AUTORESIZER_HPP

#include <QObject>

class QHeaderView;

class AutoResizer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QHeaderView *m_header;
public:
    AutoResizer(QHeaderView *parent = 0);

private slots:
    // Listen to resized sections
    void sectionResized(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize);
};

#endif // AUTORESIZER_HPP
```

**AutoResizer.cpp**

```
#include "AutoResizer.hpp"

#include <QHeaderView>

AutoResizer::AutoResizer(QHeaderView *parent) : QObject(parent), m_header(parent)
{
    // Connect ourselves to the section resize signal
    connect(m_header,SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)),SLOT(sectionResized(int,int,int)));

    // Enable last column to stretch as we don't do that ourselves
    m_header->setStretchLastSection(true);
}

void AutoResizer::sectionResized(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize)
{
    // Do some bookkeeping
    int count = m_header->model()->columnCount(QModelIndex());
    int length = m_header->width(); // The width of the headerview widget
    int sum = m_header->length(); // The total length of all sections combined

    // Check whether there is a discrepancy
    if(sum != length) {
        // Check if it's not the last header
        if(logicalIndex < count) {
            // Take the next header size (the one right to the resize handle)
            int next_header_size = m_header->sectionSize(logicalIndex+1);
            // If it can shrink
            if(next_header_size > (sum - length)) {
                // shrink it
                m_header->resizeSection(logicalIndex+1, next_header_size - (sum - length));
            } else {
                // The next header can't shrink, block the resize by setting the old size again
                m_header->resizeSection(logicalIndex, oldSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some caveats. I haven't tested this on reorder-able headers, it talks about "logicalIndices" which might mean you need some translation using `sectionPosition`. It also doesn't do much when the view is made smaller though it will fix itself once a column is being resized. And you should look whether setting the ResizeMode to Stretch doesn't already sufficiently solve your issue.